# Maven release plugin: create tag withhout SNAPSHOT depencencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I am using the Maven release plugin and I am trying to make a release. When I am on master (I am using Git) I have SNAPSHOT versions for both my project (multimodule) and also for my dependencies (also multimodule).

Suppose I want to make a tag from master (skipping the creation of a branch) where no SNAPSHOTs are used.

This is my simplified pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>results</artifactId>
<version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Results parent module</name>

<modules>
    <module>results-web</module>
    <module>results-persistence</module>
    <module>results-domain</module>
    <module>results-logic</module>
    <module>results-logic-api</module>
    <module>results-ear</module>
    <module>results-configuration</module>
    <module>results-rules-ejb</module>
    <module>results-rules</module>
    <module>results-rest</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <dependency1.version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</main.version>
    <dependency2.version>3.4.5-SNAPSHOT</main.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
                    <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.my.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency1-domain</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency1.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.my.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency1-enumerations</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency1.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.my.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency1-logic</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency1.version}</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.my.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency2-domain</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.my.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency2-enumerations</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.my.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency2-logic</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency2.version}</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

If I do:

> mvn release:prepare -Darguments="-dependency1.version=1.2.3.0
>   -Ddependency2.version=3.4.5.0"

That creates a branch that still has SNAPSHOT dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <dependency1.version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</main.version>
    <dependency2.version>3.4.5-SNAPSHOT</main.version>
</properties>
```

How would I generate a tag where the part above would be:

```
<properties>
        <dependency1.version>1.2.3.0</main.version>
        <dependency2.version>3.4.5.0</main.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 3):

The release plugin cannot change dependency versions in the POM that are not part of the reactor.

Try the [Maven Versions Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/). You can use [versions:use-releases](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/use-releases.html) to replace all snapshot dependencies with the corresponding releases. If you would like to replace them manually (perhaps because the versions differ from the snapshots) you can use versions:set. But both do not work with dependency versions supplied in properties. For properties [versions:update-properties](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/update-properties.html) is used with the setting allowSnapshots=false. This goal works automatically if no special version ranges are required but it is configurable to deal with such requirements, too.

You can configure the release plugin to call your versions plugin using [preparaionGoals](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#preparationGoals) as Stephen stated: `<preparationGoals>clean versions:use-releases verify</preparationGoals>`

Or you call the versions plugin manually before the release, e.g. with

> mvn versions:use-releases scm:checkin -Dmessage="Release versions of dependencies"

Answer (score 0):

The release plugin is not designed to address this use case.

You might be able to get somewhere by hijacking `preparationGoals` and `completionGoals` to call plugins that edit your pom... Certainly that was the use case I had in mind when I added `completionGoals`

But for now, in the absence of being able to get a plugin to edit and unedit your pom to set the versions you will have to live with editing by hand